# There is a better way of avoiding null inputs in Console.ReadLine instead of if statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

Everthing if fine with the code by now but there is a better method to avoid null inputs in Console.ReadLine, I already have tried if statement but the code end up looking like a mess.

```
class ColocarMoedas
{
    public static void Colocar(MaquinaUsuario user)
    {
        int m1, m5, m10, m25, m50;

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("/////////////////////////MOEDAS////////////////////////////");
        Console.Write("1 Centavo: ");
        m1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("5 Centavo: ");
        m5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("10 Centavo: ");
        m10 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("25 Centavo: ");
        m25 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("50 Centavo: ");
        m50 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        user.Adicionar(m1, m5, m10, m25, m50);

        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a better way of avoiding null inputs in `Console.ReadLine`
> instead of if statements

The answer is yes.

Though it's worth noting, there are more things that can go wrong with *user input* than just `null`. In fact `null` is pretty rare, it's everything else you need to worry about.

The most *idiomatic* way to validate *user numeric input* is with `TryParse` style methods, which return a *bool* when the value can't be *parsed* and returns a *value* through an `out` parameter when `true`.

[`Int32.TryParse Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
> integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
> succeeded.

You can take it a step further by using a validation loop

```
int m1 = 0;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out m1))
   Console.WriteLine("You hard one job! Now try again");
```

Essentially the above says, while the number can't be converted to an integer, which includes typos, empty input, and Ctrl+c (null), write a message.